# AES Decryption not working

Tags: android, aes

In my project i am working on AES encryption and Decryption.i have used this algorithm to encrypt and  decryption a string and storing the string in the sq-lite database.Now i get that encrypted key from database and try to decryption it but it shows an Exception (pad Block corrupted).I am converting the Encrypted string into the bytes by using

```
 public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));}
    return data;
}
```

and getting the correct Bytes but while converted into the String it shows 'pad block corrupted'.
Thanks in advance.really appreciate if find answer.
my code is

```
dh=new data_helper(Resy.this);
        mac_db=dh.getData();

//        getdata=mac_db.toString();

        KeyGenerator kgen;
        try {
            kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");

             kgen.init(128); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available

  // Generate the secret key specs.
                SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
                byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();

                SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");


                // Instantiate the cipher

                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                         getdata=mac_db.toString();
//              byte g1[]=getdata.getBytes();
//              System.out.println(g1);

        byte b[]=hexStringToByteArray(getdata);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] m1=cipher.doFinal(b);   // here pad block corrupt exception came.
                String originalString_mac = new String(original_macadress);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Original : " +originalString_mac + " " + asHex(original_macadress) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Zero accept raman, accept some answers to your previous questions first - the answer is all too easy, but until you accept some answers...

Comment: Still don't understand why it's so hard to accept a solution as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do Base64 encoding of it to get proper AES encrypt/decrypt to work.

Do it as follows.

For encrytion : Original String --> Aes encryption > base64 encode --->(encrypted string)

For decryption : encrypted string ---> base64 decode > aes decryption ---> Original String

Comment: You certainly don't _have_ to use Base64 -- that's just one way to convert a binary blob to a string. Hex encoding or anything reversible will work just as well.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure your data is the correct length and there are not errors in your hex conversion. Next you need to use the same key for encryption and decryption. From the code above it looks like you are generating a new key every time. This will not work: even if the decryption succeeds you will get something very different from the original plain text. Then `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");` might produce a cipher using a random IV, which you will need to decrypt. It is better to specify an explicit transformation string like so:

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

In short, find a working sample and start there. Something like [this](http://www.rsa.com/products/bsafe/documentation/cryptoj35html/doc/dev_guide/group__CJ__SAMPLES__AES__JCE.html).